# Javascript Tamagotchi on Background - JS worker and/or options

Tags: javascript, background-process, web-worker

This is my first time-ever question on here so I hope I am doing this correctly.

I can write and read html/css and my javascript is quite basic, I think. I use codepen to find scripts and adjust them. These are my two 'projects' I wanted to combine:

https://codepen.io/Manouki/pen/KKrEKNx
https://codepen.io/Manouki/pen/WNYmXQd

The idea is a tamagotchi-alike in which the timer would last several days / a week. It becoming an application to monitor your own well-being with. Just, now that I thought I was nearly finished, I noticed the timer freezes when I don't use the tab.

I read about Web workers and am here first asking for advice. Is it possible to create a tamagotchi, working on the background via web workers and/or are there perhaps other options I am missing?

I use;
`setInterval(function(){ update(); }, 3000);`

As a timer (I do hope I am using the correct words)

Then:

```js
function update() {
    // Decrease health stats
    geluk -= 1;
    honger -= 1;
    slapen -= 1;
    drink -= 1;
    wandelen -= 1;
    liefde -= 1;
    
    updateStats();
}
```

Short question:

- To create a tamagotchi-alike application via Javascript. Is the only option for it to run on the background, a JS web-worker, or are there other options?
- Will a web-worker surely work?

Comment: `web worker` won't work you need `service worker`

Comment: You would need localStorage to hold values between reloads